# How to track spent time to other task?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

Usually when I start to do something, then call `org-clock-in` on task in Org Mode. Sometimes when changing tasks I forget to call `org-clock-in`. How can I make `org-clock-out` for the current task and `org-clock-in` for the following with a custom time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any such function that would allow you to stop the current clock and start a new one while adjusting the end and start times with a given value. I hope someone figures out how to write one.

Meanwhile your best option is to use org-clock-convenience package, https://github.com/dfeich/org-clock-convenience, that allows you to adjust clock times and then fill gaps between clocks. The catch is that tasks have to be visible in the org agenda.